# How to set HDMI sound output as default on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio

I am using an old laptop as a dvd player, so I want the sound to always play via HDMI, but whenever I suspend the sound switches back to the internal speakers. I can change the sound back to HDMI with this command:

```
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

I've edited /etc/pulse/default.pa as follows:

```
load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false #added restore_device=false
...
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available #commented this out
...
set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo #added at end of file
```

This makes HDMI the default when the computer boots, but on suspend it still switches back to internal speakers. How can I permanently make HDMI default? If it helps, the output of `pacmd list-cards` is:

```
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xf6000000 irq 30"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "3b56"
    device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            device.product.name = "LG TV"
```

Update: for some reason, copying /etc/pulse/ to ~/.config/pulse made it work. No idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue. I followed what @Nebuzaradan said in the update and it worked. I had tried lots of other methods listed on forums and none of them worked, but for some reason, this does.

So to reiterate, to fix this issue please:

> copy /etc/pulse/ to ~/.config/pulse