# detecting monitor wakeup

Tags: debian, xfce, udev, pulseaudio, hdmi

Context: Debian/testing on a ASRock B450 with Ryzen 2200G, HDMI monitor.

In order to reset [Pulseaudio default sink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489302/re-set-xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin-default-after-hdmi-monitor-standby/490616#490616) I need to know when the monitor comes back from standby so that I can run a script to change the default PA sink and, possibly, [move existing streams](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index39h3).

So far, these are my options, sorted by increasing difficulty and efficiency:

1. polling /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/dpms
2. parsing the output of "xset"
3. parsing the output of "pactl subscribe" (as suggested in the linked question)
4. writing a Pulseaudio application (idem)

I have tried using "udevadm monitor" but apparently only plug / unplug events are tracked, not standby / wakeup. Is there an easy way to do this? By that I mean as easy as writing a udev rule can be. I'm asking out of curiosity, really, since polling the dpms file would work nicely: it is accurate and reasonably robust, since it requires no parsing.